# How long does a bountied question stay in the featured questions tab?

Tags: support, bounty

I read the description, and it says 7 days.

Does that mean even if I increment the bounty from 50 reputation points to 100 reputation points it will still be there for the same 7 days or it would increased to 14 days since I am adding new bounty to my question?

Comment: If it changed based on how much you pay, don't you think that would be spelled out where the 7 days is? It's 7 days whether you pay 50 rep or 500.

Comment: *don't you think that would be spelled out* @Kendra There's **a lot** of things I'd think would get spelled out that aren't.  (That's not aimed at Stack Overflow. Most sites don't give enough information.)

Comment: @BSMP That's true enough. I would expect Stack Exchange would have spelled this one out, if it were the case, though.

Comment: @yellowantphil Hah! You sure? And if I get bounty for the 2nd time, does it have to be 100? If that is the case then I wonder why I got 3 downvotes!?

Comment: Yes, your second bounty will have to be double the value of the first. I didn't downvote, but I would guess the ones who did may have for "lack of research". (I see it as asking clarification and valid, regardless of my first comment.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty seems to cover this adequately.

Comment: @CodyGray I got an answer here, but it seems vague there. can u paste where it says u can extend it for another 7 days? If you seee the first comment here, it shows the common understanding that you can't extend

Comment: @CodyGray till when do I have time to offer the additional bounty? Can I do that in the last hour of the grace period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on yellowwantphil's comment and this [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

> Additionally, if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, the
>   minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation on
>   the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third, and
>   so on).

The minimum amount doubles each time. So you could start four bounties and get a total of 28 days on the featured section. The system won't let you do an 800-rep bounty, so you'll have to stop after the fourth bounty.

What I don't know is til *when* do you have time to post the new bounty so you avoid the automatic rewarding of the bounty? likely it's before the end of the grace period...

Comment: I think I read somewhere recently that the mandatory doubling in cost stops at 500 rep, so you can keep bountying the same question forever, if you can afford the 500-rep cost for each bounty. I don't have a link though.

Comment: @yellowantphil there is one way to find out.